# Showing the 100 most recently added products

Tags: product, collection, cms

I want to add a page to my Magento site which displays the 100 most recently added products sorted by date added. I want this page to appear like a normal category page with pagination and layered navigation.

I was wondering if this is possible in Magento as I've read that layered navigation needs to work on one specific category, whereas I need it to work across multiple.

Ideally I would like a solution which adds layered navigation to any product collection as I would like to create a few different pages with different lists of products that will all need the layered navigation added.
Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible but You want categories and product attributes in layer navigation?

Comment: You can use my Dynamic Category Products extension. It can do this easy, and lots lots more. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dynamic-category-products-automated-category-products-shop-by-brands-shop-by-any-attribute.html

Comment: Set Product as New from Date & Set Product as New to Date two product attributes available in admin. Have you filter this attributes base or filter created date?

Comment: Try this way : http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination/

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are:

1. Write a block that queries for those products, write a template that copies the category layout. ***This is the worst choice***
2. Realise that you want a category that contains the 100 most recently added products and then

   1. Write a cron job to update the contents of that category with the latest products. It's a great learning experience if you want it, but personally when I do this I commit the crime of writing an sql script to do it instead. ***This is an ok choice, the sql script is bad advice though***
   2. Realise that time is money, and unless you particularly want the learning experience give @ProxieBlue his $99 for an extension that does what you want and more, written by someone who has a fair bit of rep and hasn't just come here to shill his extension. ***This is the wise choice***

Answer (score -1):

You can get 100 products with this below code:

```
 $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('status','1')
                         ->setOrder('entity_id','desc');
$_productCollection->setPageSize('100');
```